# why this loop cannot stop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use jquery(jquery-2.1.1) and constructor function to build html. But when I tried this method in for loop, the loop can't stop. Can anyone tell me why it happens?

Here' s the code. Thanks a lot.

```
function tag() {
    this.addClass = function(...theArgs) {
        for (index in theArgs) {
            this.$html.addClass(theArgs[index]);
        }       
    }

    this.setAttr = function(attr, value) {
        this.$html.attr(attr, value);
    }

    this.append = function(...theArgs) {
        for (index in theArgs) {
            this.$html.append(theArgs[index]);
        }
    }

    this.find = function(value) {
        return this.$html.find(value);
    }

    this.empty = function() {
        this.$html.empty();
    }

    this.remove = function(value) {
        this.find(value).remove();
    }

    this.clone = function() {
        return jQuery.extend(true, {}, this);
    }

    this.show = function() {
        return this.$html[0];
    }
}

function label(text) {
    tag.call(this);

    this.$html = $("<label></label>");
    this.append(text);
}


for(var index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
        var fieldLabel = new label(1);
        console.log(index);
}
```

Comment: You have an undeclard `index` in `.append()`, and they're conflicting: `for (index in theArgs) {`. Be sure to declare your variables: `for (var index in theArgs) {`

Comment: ...also in `addClass()`. Use a linter like ESLint to find these common errors. It'll save you lots and lots of time.

Comment: ...and using `for-in` on an Array isn't a great idea in JS. Since you're using `...` syntax, you must be OK with ES6 stuff, so I'd suggest using a `for-of` loop.

Comment: why? why are you re-wrapping std jquery functionality in this mess?

Comment: I've written similar functionality in the past, but in the end the views became seriously bloated and inefficient. A year later I switched to a templating system instead and never looked back. They render faster and the view code became much smaller.

Comment: @Shilly yeh...I' m a newbie on the js, so I didn't find the most efficient way at first time. I will try to use template system later, thanks a lot~

Comment: There's alot to learn from trying, so good luck, keep at it and enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you use the `index` (without `var`) as the running variable for all loops in your `tag` function. That `index` variable is still effective in the outer scope of the `for-loop` at the end (which should stop with the condition `>=2`).

At the beginning of the loop, `index` is `0`. The next loop it should be `1`. But when going into the inner `append` method, it's reset back to `0` due to the loop `for-in` (the argument passed in is just `1`, so the spread notation makes an array of 1 length, and `for-in` stops with `index` set to `0`) . So at the end of the second loop it is still `0`. That means it will never become greater the value `1` (which is increased only at the beginning of the `for-loop`). The condition `< 2` will always be satisfied and the `for-loop` just runs forever.

You can either use another name for the running variable in `for-in`. Or just declare another local-scoped `index` by using `var`, like this:

```
this.append = function(...theArgs) {
    for (var index in theArgs) {
        this.$html.append(theArgs[index]);
    }
}
```

Or better using `for-of` as someone suggested.

Comment: @CharlesZhou if it helps, please take your time accepting the answer. Otherwise you should delete your question because looks like it's just a simple mistake and not taken benefit by others.